# Proofs involving Gradient

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to prove the following

$$\bigtriangledown ||\textbf{v}|| = \dfrac{1}{||\textbf{v}||} \textbf{v}$$

and

$$\bigtriangledown (||\textbf{v}||^2) = 2\textbf{v}$$

I'm very confused about how I should proceed. I know that $\bigtriangledown = <v_x, v_y>$ tried rewriting $||\textbf{v}||$ as $\sqrt{v_1^2 + \cdots + v_n^2}$ but it didn't get me anywhere. If someone can please help, I would really appreciate it .

Comment: $||v||$ is not what you have written- perhaps a correct starting point will help you?

Comment: oh I'm sorry I will edit that. I meant to square the components

Comment: Also, what's $v_x$ and $v_y$ isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry I will fix that too. I meant the partial derivatives. So, $\bigtriangledown$ = <partial derivative with respect to x, partial derivative with respect to y>....what is the correct notation for that? Thank you so much for your help btw

Comment: keep it as the gradient symbol- you do not need to specify what it is... for a function of $n$ variables anyway the formula for the gradient that you wrote isn't correct.

Comment: oh okay I would have n variables so I would need a partial derivative with respect to each variable? I don't completely understand how to use this notation, I'm sorry.

Comment: yes manny: you would need partial derivative wrt each of the variables.

Comment: okay how would I move on from there? Since $||\textbf{v}||$ is a scalar while $\bigtriangledown$ is a vector, would I multiply the scalar into the vector?

Comment: I wrote the answer- hope it helps :).

Comment: thank you so much! I'll try to use what you did to figure out the first one. Just as a quick question, what does this mean $\bigtriangledown ||\textbf{v}||$? There are no parentheses around $||\textbf{v}||$ in this case.

Comment: I think we should read it as $\bigtriangledown (||v||)$. $(\bigtriangledown f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n})$

Comment: thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$||v||^2=(v_1^2+\cdots v_n^2)$. Now, $\bigtriangledown (||v||^2)= (\frac{\partial}{\partial v_1}(v_1^2+\cdots v_n^2),\cdots,(\frac{\partial}{\partial v_n}(v_1^2+\cdots v_n^2)=2(v_1,v_2, \cdots , v_n)=2v$.

Also, you know that $\bigtriangledown (||v||^2)=2||v||(\bigtriangledown (||v||))$, by the chain rule. So, by the above computation,

$\bigtriangledown (||v||)=\frac{v}{||v||}$